# Ubuntu Touch change scope "today"

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

Does anyone knows how to change the content of scope today?
The news displayed there are totally unusable for me. I'm from germany and really not interested in news from El Pais or Cinco Dias. 
Is there a way to add different content? Maybe somewhere in the configs?
Would be fine to make my M10 tablet more usable...

Cheers, Frank

Comment: Ahh... I read some other questions here and the answer is clear... Those scopes can´t be edited and are fixed. Not good and quiet limited in my opinion but what can I do. Hope this will be fixed some time

Comment: I hve added RSS scope and this displays me my german news RSS on "today" scope. Works well for me and I have disabled all the default news sources there...

Comment: Same experience with me... So far, these pre-installed scopes are, to be polite, absolutely useless to me. I've fiddled around quite a few times but could not figure out how to add content sources I would rather like to access. Same with Audio and Video scopes. Arbitrary content which I have absolutely no affiliation with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the today scope in M10 does not differ from the today scope on other devices, there is few customization possible. Clicking on the settings menu in the upper right (in between the star and the magnifying glass) you can choose some content. As for German news I have though only DIE WELT available (using the aquaris E4.5).

Comment: Yes, I know. But this customisation is only limited to the preinstalled scopes like you mentioned. It would make sense to add own sources but it seems that this is not possible :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate all the scopes you don't want by unticking their boxes in the scope configuration. You have to trigger the clog icon to reach the settings menu for the content of a scope page or indeed by swiping up from the bottom to choose amongst a general scope page. Not sure I remember correctly without it in front of me, but you should get there quite easily.

Then, if you browse for scopes in the store and install them, you'll have the possibility to activate them within the Today's scope (or by adding a new scope page). 
I removed all scopes I'm not interested in from Today's scope and added those I wanted (Belgian newspapers). Just do some digging around within the scopes and you should find the customization options.

You can also choose how many news you want to see per scope or how many photos per photo app, etc...

Answer (score -1):

You get access to more configuration by pulling up from the bottom middle in the scopes. Easy to miss, unsure if it'll solve your issue though.

Comment: Pulling up from the middle of the scope will enable you to add moe scopes, but not to configure the today scope.